# YAML current date

Tags: yaml, octobercms

How in YAML set current date?

```
processing_time:
            label: 'Procesing time'
            mode: date
            minDate: '2016-04-14'
            span: auto
            default: ''
            type: datepicker
```

I need to change **minDate** value to **today's** date (curent date). I do it in OctoberCms...

Comment: That is just a string scalar that looks like a date and it  is **not** a scalar that is a date (it would not have quotes if it was). Just update the string and write out the file again.

Comment: I need today's date string to "minDate" value.... Maybe I can use variable in YAML ?

Comment: There are no variables in YAML. You would need to solve this on the YAML text before handing it to the YAML parser, or after parsing by walking the tree structure and updating the field.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve that by set `minDate` with `now` text

```
.
.
minDate: now
.
```